# DNS config for several mail subdomains pointing to Google Apps

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, g-suite

I have a domain mydomain.com. Its MX records are currently pointing to Google Apps:

```
mydomain.com.       300 IN MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
mydomain.com.       300 IN MX 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
mydomain.com.       300 IN MX 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
mydomain.com.       300 IN MX 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
mydomain.com.       300 IN MX 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
```

I'm configuring [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/) for transactional email which should be sent from subdomain `email.mydomain.com`.

SparkPost requires me to confirm access to these mailboxes:

- `abuse@email.mydomain.com`
- `postmaster@email.mydomain.com`

Hence I've added the subdomain to Google Apps as an alias. But how do I configure my DNS records?

Do I need to create all 5 MX entries for the new subdomain? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You create them exactly the same way.

Comment: So there is no shortcut? Like, say, creating a CNAME record?